# Maven Minify Plugin - Pom Directory?

Tags: maven, plugins, pom.xml, minify

I'm using NetBeans to develop and am trying to run a 'clean and build' on a Maven project.  I'm getting the following error:

> The POM for com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:jar:1.7.2 is
>   missing, no dependency information available

I found the pom for the plugin [here], but am not sure where it should be stored, and if it should be altered in any way .
 Can anyone help?  Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like you have some kind of network / proxy etc. issues in your area....

Comment: I am indeed behind a proxy, but I've configured that in settings.xml so it shouldn't be a problem..,